# drop-shadow CSS function makes app laggy in Firefox mobile

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, svg-filters

I'm making a pomodoro clock in React and apply an animated `filter: drop-shadow` on an svg circle timer to make it look like it pulses.

This works fine on my Firefox desktop browser, but it makes my whole app laggy on Firefox mobile on my Android device. The app works fine on the Chrome mobile browser.

I noticed the app is still laggy even if I remove the animation and only apply a static `filter: drop-shadow` to the svg element. Is there a fix for this, or perhaps another way to achieve the effect I want?

Here is a [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/7370zn4m0j) for my app.

The relevant svg code is in PomodoroTimer.jsx, or here:

```
    <svg width="17em" height="17em" viewBox="0 0 20em 20em">
      <circle
        cx="8.5em"
        cy="8.5em"
        r="5.8em"
        fill="none"
        stroke="#FFF"
        strokeWidth=".05em"
      />
    </svg>
    <svg
      className="pulse"
      width="17em"
      height="17em"
      viewBox="0 0 20em 20em"
    >
      <circle
        cx="8.5em"
        cy="8.5em"
        r="5.8em"
        fill="none"
        stroke="#FFF"
        strokeWidth=".2em"
        strokeDasharray="36.442em"
        strokeDashoffset={36.442 * this.props.offsetModifier + "em"}
      />
    </svg>
```

And the relevant CSS is in PomodoroTimer.css, or here:

```
svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

@-webkit-keyframes svg_pulse {
  0% {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.5em #fff);
  }
  50% {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 1.5em #fff);
  }
  100% {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.5em #fff);
  }
}

@keyframes svg_pulse {
  0% {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.5em #fff);
  }
  50% {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 1.5em #fff);
  }
  100% {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.5em #fff);
  }
}

.pulse {
  -webkit-animation: svg_pulse 3s linear infinite;
  animation: svg_pulse 3s linear infinite;
}
```

Comment: try putting the filter on the circle, rather than the svg element

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately the problem remains.